# How to retain view\page state in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic2 app in which I have couple of pages. On click of a button in 1st page, I navigate to 2nd page and on ionViewDidLoad(of 2nd page), I am calling data service and rendering the data in a list.
Next, when I navigate back by clicking back button on top, I go to 1st page. Now again, if i click on the button in 1st page, I navigate to 2nd page. However, in this case, service call is made again, which means ionViewDidLoad is triggered again (which is what i want to avoid)

How can I retain the previous state of the 2nd view? I am not using setRoot. I am using push and pop of the navigator.

Comment: You can share a service where you can retain the data and avoid calling two times to you web api. Make the service a singleton instance (add it as a provider on your main module) and you will always have the same data.

Comment: Can you add the `ionViewWillUnload` hook on the 2nd page and log something there? I'm curious if it gets called after you leave the 2nd page.

Comment: Andreas, Yes it does destroy and create new instance everytime. ionViewWillUnload is also triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this re-calling of the constructor and of `ionViewDidLoad()` in any page after push and pop is an intended behavior in Ionic 2 (see  [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5960)).

Since you are already using a data service to get the data for each page, you could keep store your data there. If you have some time-consuming data loading e.g. from a database, you could store the loaded data in the service and return it to a page in the following calls.

For example in `data-service.ts`:

```
public getData() {
   // data already loaded, just return it 
   if (this.data) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
   }
   // data not loaded yet, get it from database
   return new Promise(resolve => {
       ... loading data from database to this.data ....
       resolve(this.data);
   });
}
```

and then in `sample-page.ts`:

```
private initData() {
    this.dataService.getData().then(data => {
        this.data = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, went through the comments there. But from developers' point of view, i guess it can be enhanced so that developer can have option to retain the existing instance or create new instance everytime. Anyway, thanks Onno. I'll go with this approach for now. Cheers!